# java.lang.NullPointerException in the Deck class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
    public class Deck {
        public static final int CARDSOFDECK = 112;
        private Card[] cards = new Card[CARDSOFDECK];

            public static void main(String[] args){
                Deck deck = new Deck();
                deck.load();
                deck.show();
        }
        public void show(){
            for(Card c: cards)
                System.out.println(c.toString());
        }
        public void load(){
            int j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                int i = 0;
                for (Color c : Color.values()) {
                    for (Value v : Value.values())
                        cards[i++] = new Card(c, v);
                }

            }

        }
    }


    public class Card {

        private Color color;

        private Value value;



        public Card(Color c, Value v) {
            color = c;
            value = v;
        }



            public String toString() {
                return color + " " + value;
            }
        }
public enum Color {
      RED("Red"), YELLOW("Yellow"), BLUE("Blue"), GREEN("Green");

      private final String cardColor;

      private Color(String cardColor){
        this.cardColor = cardColor;
      }

      public String getColor(){
        return cardColor;
      }
}



public enum Value {
      ZERO(0), ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9),
      SKIP(10), DRAW2(11), REVERSE(12), WILD(13), WILDDRAW4(14);

      private final int cardValue;

      private Value(int cardValue){
        this.cardValue = cardValue;
      }

      public int getValue(){
        return cardValue;

      }
}
```

I am getting a nullpointerexception in the Deck class around where it says toString about halfway down, and I am not too sure why. I am making an uno game for my java based class and am trying to get the cards created. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `private Card[] cards = new Card[CARDSOFDECK];` creates room for 112 cards; but it doesn't create **any** cards.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  he create cards in load() method.

Comment: @ZinMinn 112 of them?

Comment: You are creating 60 cards only (15 values and 4 colors).. `cards[59]` is your last card. There is no card in `cards[60]` and upwards, hence the NullPointerException (your `cards` array has 112 slots but only 60 cards - 52 slots are empty).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  you means he created 120 cards??

Comment: All of the cards are shown when I run it, but I get the exception after they are created. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below

```
public void load(){
  int j = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Color c : Color.values()) {
      for (Value v : Value.values())
        cards[i++] = new Card(c, v);
    }
  }
}
```

You reset `i` to 0 within the `j` for loop. What you intend to do (i assume) is declare it as 0 outside the loop in order to make two copies of each card. To do that, change it to the below:

```
public void load(){
  int j = 0;
  int i = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    for (Color c : Color.values()) {
      for (Value v : Value.values())
        cards[i++] = new Card(c, v);
    }
  }
}
```

Just as a side note, I think you also want to have 120 cards, not 112. 15 card types * 4 colors * 2 of each card = 120.

Comment: Thank you so much! You found exactly where my mistake was!

Comment: @BrianRobinson No problem, happy to help! If this solved your problem I'd really appreciate it if you accepted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
 public void load(){
        int j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            int i = 0;  //<-- i is reset during the next loop
            for (Color c : Color.values()) {
                for (Value v : Value.values())
                    cards[i++] = new Card(c, v);
            }

        }
```

i is reset to 0 at the second loop. Which means half of you cards[] will not be initialized.

```
 public void load(){
        int j = 0;
        int i = 0; // <-- move i = 0 here
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            //int i = 0;  //<-- i is reset during the next loop
            for (Color c : Color.values()) {
                for (Value v : Value.values())
                    cards[i++] = new Card(c, v);
            }

        }
```

also, 112 not semms have enought space.

```
public static final int CARDSOFDECK = 120;
```

would be better.